# Linq query for sorting by date, then by status, then by name

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, iqueryable

Code:

```
IQueryable<Task> taskRecord = parentId != Guid.Empty ? _taskReadService.GetRecords()
                             .Where(x => x.TaskId == taskId).OrderBy(x => x.Date)
```

I sorted the **date** using above code and it was working **fine**. I need to add another **two** conditions after date is sorted, that is **by status** and **by name**.

Comment: Did you use `ThenBy` instead of `OrderBy` for other items than the first one?

Comment: No, I didn't used `ThenBy`. If possible, change the above code and post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As *Caramiriel* suggested use `ThenBy`

```
IQueryable<Task> taskRecord = parentId != Guid.Empty ? _taskReadService.GetRecords()
                             .Where(x => x.TaskId == taskId)
                             .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
                             .ThenBy(x => x.Status)
                             .ThenBy(x => x.Name) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd re format the code slightly for readability....

```
IQueryable<Task> taskRecord = null;
if(parentId != Guid.Empty)
{
     taskRecord = _taskReadService.GetRecords()
                                  .Where(x => x.TaskId == taskId)
                                  .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
                                  .ThenBy(x => x.Status)
                                  .ThenBy(x => x.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'll need is `ThenBy`. Adding a second `OrderBy` resets the sorting order (actually performs the sorting, followed by resorting for another time). By extrapolating the example:

```
IQueryable<Task> taskRecord =
    parentId != Guid.Empty
    ? _taskReadService.GetRecords()
        .Where(x => x.TaskId == taskId)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
        .ThenBy(x => x.Status)
        .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
    : ... ;
```